# Dependency injection : should I completely hide implementation and take a dependency on the container or keep my implementation and constructor public

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I've a app with 3 dll (web.dll, businesslogic.dll and services.dll). The web apps instanciate business logic objects that use services. All services are "hidden" behind interfaces and I use autofac to inject thoses implementations to the business logic objects. Nothing fancy here.

I'm trying to create a better encapsulation for my app by making the interfaces of my services public but hiding the implementation of my types by making them internal. With Autofac auto registration, it works well unless the constructor has some value type parameter like a connection string. I have 3 alternatives with pros and cons on each so I was wondering which one would be considered the best :

1. Replace all my value parameters with interfaces (ex : IMyServiceConfigurations), which works great but creates a lot of 1 property interfaces and implementations that obfuscated a bit the constructors
2. Put the registration in an autofac module into my service dll. Doing that, I take a dependency on Autofac in the services dll which I don't really like. I prefer that only the root of the application (the web app) to take a dependency on the container
3. Use NamedParameter or TypedParameter but for that, the root of the application need to know the constructor that will be used (and the implementation) so the encapsulation is broken in another way.

Any idea or comments on how to achieve that without leaking the implementation outside the service dll.

Thanks.

Comment: One trick in those cases is to inject a factory instead of the actual instance. For instance, with a repository pattern, you would inject `IRepositoryFactory` instead of `IRepository`. And your factory would define a method `Create(string connectionString)` that returns a `IRepository`. Since your factory knows about the repository implementation, it can directly call the constructor

Comment: I'm not sure. Doing that, you push the need to know the configuration to the business logic layer. I think it actually makes thing worst by leaking implementation details to another layer. Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think it solves my problem.

Comment: @KooKiz: Factory abstractions are [hardly ever](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100) the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a better encapsulation for my app by making the interfaces of my services public but hiding the implementation of my types by making them internal

Making classes internal doesn't change anything considering encapsulation. Since your components depend on abstractions, there is no difference in encapsulation from the consumer's perspective. They still don't know about the existence of the implementation. This can be exaggerated when you move the implementation to a different assembly that the consumer has no dependency on. In this way the implementation can remain public without the consumer to be able to use it directly.

Besides this, even if the implementation is public, it will typically still protect its invariants by making everything internal except parts that are exposed by the interface it implements. This means it is still applying encapsulation, even though it is public.

In a Line of Business application, you typically gain nothing by making implementations internal. Nobody outside your application will be trying to use these types. There are two consumers of these implementations though. Those consumers are your unit tests and the application's [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). For both of them it only makes your job harder if you make them internal.

Reconsider making those types public.

Comment: The goal I have is, by making the implementation internal, I'm pretty sure that the developpers will not use the implementation instead of the interface because they can easily instanciate it. I agree with you that if the interface is used everywhere, it's the same thing but I want them to fall in the pit of success by making hard (or impossible) the behavior I want to prevent. I'm aware of the unit test difficulty, which can be made easier by allow the test project (and only this one) to see internal types.

Comment: Of course, I can solve this problem with other technics like code review but I'm curious to find a way to prevent this at the compiler level. Thanks.

Comment: @mberube.net you dhould solve this using the SOLID principles. If you look at the Dependency Inversion Principle, it states that the upper layer should define the abstraction. So you should invert the dependency: put the interfaces in the same assembly as the consumers and let the implementations depend on the consumer assembly.

Comment: It's an interesting suggestion. I never thought of the problem that way. I can see pros and cons to this. Thanks for the idea.